# How can I activate MySQL Database Server?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a problem with my xampp that's installed on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

After successfully installing my xampp server, I do get access to the lampp server which further indicates that the mysql database is running.

But when I click the xampp status, it's indicated the mysql database is deactivated. Also my phpmyadmin show this error:`The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)`.

This has been the problem with me for the past 72 hours and I am still struggling with how to make it activated?

Can anyone help me with this?

When I click <kbd>Start</kbd>,

[image]

Then,
[image]

Comment: How did you install server? Did you customize anything after setup? Provide more information about your installation process.

Comment: Waw thanks for your input, now phpmyadmin is responding fine. It seems I have another constrain; I normally lunch my apache2 through this command:"/opt/lampp/lampp start" just of recent, I can't see the directive any more. the directive "/lampp" is no where to be seen? Also I search all roots but I can't see folder lampp on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop. If i try to reinstall the xampp it pups me the features are running fine but I can't able to lunch any of it. Any ideas appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start mysql server through command line.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: I meet the same problem. I already tried the above two solutions.The terminal shows me "start: Job is already running: mysql" but when I check the status of MySQL in "http://localhost/xampp/index.php", it is still deactivated. How to fix it?

Comment: use command "kill" to stop the server process that working in background and try the above command again

Answer (score 0):

Mysql was not activated. The following commands helped me fix it.
Stop xampp using the command

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Restart it with

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 0):

the most probable culprit is the default mysql instance

stop the running mysql instance

`sudo service mysql stop`

***using cli***

(re)start the lampp service

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`  or  `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

(re)start mysql instance only again

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql` or reload as follows  `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp reloadmysql`

***using gui***
click start

...for the posterity...